# qt-faststart command never finish

Tags: ffmpeg, qt-faststart

I am trying to use qt-faststart on MP4 videos to make the streaming fast but the qt-faststart command is never get finish, It is running from the last one and half hour and video file is of 14MB only.

```
qt-faststart file.mp4 newfile.mp4
```

The command is showing the `ftyp` and `free` as output

the output look like this and it is keep repeating these lines and increasing the number

```
ftyp 2324322  32
free 2324456   8
```

and the number is keep increasing with the output. No error is shown.

The MP4 video is converted from FLV video using the FFMPEG.

Generally it show the output like this but with my installation of qt-faststart I never get this ouput

```
    patching stco atom...
    patching stco atom..
    writing ftyp atom...
    writing moov atom...
    copying rest of file ...
```

What could be the issue?
Is there anything wrong with the installation of qt-faststart?

I am on `Linux 2.6.18-128.2.1.el5PAE i686`

Comment: Please provide all necessary information so the issue can be duplicated; including your ffmpeg command that you used to convert the video, the complete ffmpeg console output, and also links to the input files if possible (for both ffmpeg and qt-faststart).

Comment: Hi, original author of qt-faststart here. Where did you get qt-faststart? Did you download a binary or compile it yourself? If the latter, how did you compile it?

Comment: @MultimediaMike: Hi, the installation part of qt-faststart is done by the system administrator so I don't have much info about this. I will get back to you with such info if it will not resolved by my system admin.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: I will update the question soon.

Comment: In my experience, problems with qt-faststart are usually due to miscompilation. Do you have privileges to a C compiler on the system (does 'cc' do anything)?

Comment: I'd use gdb on it and pause it when it's frozen and see where the threads are.

Answer (score 0):

Check your paths to the files.
This works for me.

C:\Users\name\Desktop\qt-faststart.exe C:\Users\name\Desktop\videos\video.mp4 C:\Users\name\Desktop\videosnewer\video.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Use the python wrapper https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart

For more info, read “Server Crash” section here http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/11/12/how-to-make-mp4-progressive-with-qt-faststart/